# iOS 6 - UIBarButtonItem setStyle not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` in a `UIToolBar`. I have set up the code like so:

```
UIBarButtonItem *barbutton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(actionSheet:)];
[barbutton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil], barButton, nil]] ;
[toolBar setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

I am expecting the barButton to show with a border, but only the built-in action icon shows up. Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

On searching around for this issue, I found out that the style that you want - `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered` gets applied when you init the `UIBarButtonItem` using `initWithImage` only.

So, maybe you could get an image for the Action button and try this

```
UIBarButtonItem *barbutton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:@"action.png" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
[barbutton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
```

Tell me if this works for you. Cheers!

---

*Edit*

Upon testing your own code, it seems to be working fine for me. The line

```
[barbutton setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];
```

will make the action buttion like this

[image]

and on commenting the above line out, I am getting a button like this

[image]

Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want. For some reason this doesn't seem to be happening for me.:(

Comment: Do check out your `toolBar` outlets with the xib file. And try Product>Clean for the current project.

Comment: How would that affect the UIBarButton?

Comment: I don't exactly know, but cleaning the project removes random errors sometimes... Your exact code was working for me, so I don't know what could possibly be wrong on your end.

Comment: Hmm. It's weird. The same code works on a UINavigationBar but not on a UIToolBar.

Comment: Surprisingly, some other SO questions are reporting the exact same thing to be working on a `UIToolBar` and __not__ on the `UINavigationBar`... Weird.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6 you can use the new method of UIBarButtonItem class:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage
              forState:(UIControlState)state
                 style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style
            barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

It sets the background image for the specified state, style, and metrics. More details are available in the [Apple docs][1]

Hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

use following code for ios 6 issue. It will be OK on IOS 7 as well.

```
UIButton* btton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[btton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem *rightButtonItem  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btton];
```